# How to establish TCP/IP connection using socket in python. I don't want it to be local, but accessable from any computers (clients) on any networks

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, server

I'm trying to set up a server that my friends can log into and access running a specialized python program, I want to use the socket module and I don't know how to make my computer an IP address that can be accessed on any network from any computer running the appropriate client python program. I just don't know how to do it.

I've tried looking into answers elsewhere, but I can't exactly pinpoint what I'm looking for

I'm just using normal example code that sets up a server and a client via an IPv4 address on a local network and within one machine. I used the socket module, which I would prefer to continue using, unless there is something better for this instance.

No unexpected results because I can't even do it in the first place, I've only achieved it on the local network and within one computer.

update: just made aware that it is because of my ISP, how to I change my assigned IP so it is addressable from clients on different networks?

Comment: Your Internet Provider has to give you proper IP Address. This part has nothing to do with your code. Your local IP is visible only on this local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own server code that binds and listens on a port.

But you'll find it more convenient to run your custom logic
under a [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) server.

Consider setting up an inexpensive contract with a hosting service,
as they are likely to offer connectivity features
that your residential ISP won't support.